# Boot Debian with external monitor as primary display device

Tags: linux, boot, debian, multiple-monitors, grub

I have an old HP laptop with non-working display. So i decided to convert the laptop to a private server. I connected it to my TV and installed Debian 7.7. The installation was smooth with the display coming on my TV. But after installing and trying to boot into Debian I am able to see only GRUB menu and after selecting the OS the display is gone. I think it is switched to monitor display.

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: I have the opposite problem (with an HP laptop, seems their displays stop working pretty soon): debian boots smoothly and during boot it recognizes the external display. But grub won't see the external display and I have to boot blindly: I cannot easily switch between different OSs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ive had this problem. if i understand correctly, you want the display of things such as the boot menu to show up on a device connected via HDMI or VGA cable, but the system only wants to use the laptop screen?
If this is the problem, my solution was disconnecting the cable for the screen of the laptop.